# I want to use onClick attribute of my button to call a function that has parameters

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, data-binding

I don't have a problem using the listenerbinding mehod to call functions in the layout files, but this function i want to call - goToNextScreen() has a parameter which is the adapter used in the fragment. Here's the Fragment code snippet:

```
class PoultryFragment : Fragment() {
...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding?.apply {
            lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

            viewModel = sharedViewModel
            val poultryOptions = datasource
            val adapter = PoultryAdapter(poultryOptions, sharedViewModel)
            poultryRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
            poultryRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
            // nextButton.setOnClickListener { updateCart(adapter) }
            poultryFragment = this@PoultryFragment
        }
    }
    fun goToNextScreen(adapter: PoultryAdapter) {

        updateCart(adapter)
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_poultryFragment_to_breweryFragment)
    }
}
```

The layout code:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".PoultryFragment">

    <data>

        ...

        <variable
            name="poultryFragment"
            type="com.rgbstudios.breakfastapp.PoultryFragment" />

    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout>
                ...
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/next_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:onClick="@{() -> poultryFragment.goToNextScreen()}"
                    android:text="@string/next_button"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Can I do it such that I wont have to set up the onclickListener in the fragment class, and do it in the layout file?

I don't know if I can add the parameter as a variable in the xml file and use it

Answer (score 0):

You could do it via layout by adding the `Adapter` as a parameter and set it the same way as you set the fragment.

```
<layout ...>

<data>

    ...

    <variable
        name="adapter"
        type="com.rgbstudios.breakfastapp.PoultryAdapter" />

</data>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    <LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout>
            ...
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/next_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="@{() -> poultryFragment.goToNextScreen(adapter)}"
                android:text="@string/next_button"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

But I don't understand why you want to do it this way instead of setting the ClickListener inside the `Fragment` as you already have the binding.

```
class PoultryFragment : Fragment() {
...
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    binding?.apply {
        lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner

        viewModel = sharedViewModel
        val poultryOptions = datasource
        val adapter = PoultryAdapter(poultryOptions, sharedViewModel)
        poultryRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
        poultryRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
        nextButton.setOnClickListener { goToNextScreen(adapter) }
    }
}
private fun goToNextScreen(adapter: PoultryAdapter) {

    updateCart(adapter)
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_poultryFragment_to_breweryFragment)
}
```

}